# How can a bootable partition be created for Windows installation media on an external HDD?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, installation

Now I'm not talking about a backup image or creating a partition that holds the entire OS to boot from, just to clarify. What I'm asking for is taking the Windows installation media, plopping that onto a partition on an external HDD, then plugging that HDD into another computer and having the ability to boot onto that partition from a BIOS menu. Is there a good way to go about this? I've seen quite a lot of tutorials out there for manipulating the Windows install media, so I hope this should be relatively easy. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want to boot the install media from a hard drive?

Comment: Yes, that is my desire!

Comment: This is called WindowsToGo ad works in Windows 8/8.1 Enterprise.

Comment: No, that's not what I want. WindowsToGo is a portable version of the entire OS. As I said: `Now I'm not talking about a backup image or creating a partition that holds the entire OS to boot from, just to clarify.`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple FAT32 partition on that USB drive - size 8 GB (so you can accommodate images bigger than 4 GB)

Then mount the source ISO and copy ALL files (admin mode) to the created partition on USB.

Then you run

```
bootsect /nt60 z: /force /mbr
```

where z: is your partition on USB drive.

Check with "Disk Management" or diskpart.exe that the USB partition is marked as active and mark it as active if it is'nt.

Now you should be able to boot from this USB drive either BIOS or UEFI way on any computer.